# How to continue this proof about image of composite relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, relations

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

Proof that if $R$ is a relation from a set $X$ to a set $Y$, $S$ is a relation from $Y$ to $Z$, and $A \subseteq X$, then $I_{SoR}(A) = I_s(I_r(A))$

---

I know the general outline of equality proof of sets: I have to prove that both sets are subsets of each other.

I first began trying to prove that $I_{sor}(A) \subseteq I_s(I_r(A))$:

Proof: Suppose $R$ is a relation from a set $X$ to a set $Y$, $S$ is a relation from a set $Y$ to a set $Z$ and $A \subset X$.
Futher suppose $z \in I_{S o R}(A)$. By the definition of image of relations of sets, there exists $a \in A$ such that $(a, z) \in S o R$.
By the definition of composition, there exists a $y$ such that $(a, y) \in R$ and $(y, z) \in S$.
From there, I think the way to go is to say that $y \in I_R(A)$ and $(y, z) \in S$, hence $z \in I_S(I_R(A))$, but I don't know if I'm making any logical mistake here.

Comment: Proof looks good to me! Last line could be made a tad clearer, but generally looks fine.